# How to use StyleCop rules to clean-up using resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop, code-cleanup

How can i make clean-up with `ReSharper` using `Settings.StyleCop` file as a rules ?
I can't do it using only `ReSharper` clean-up settings.
I use `Visual Studio` 2013 and 2015.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using StyleCop - Resharper Ultimate Extention:
[image: StyleeCop - Resharper Ultimate Extention]

Resharper -> Extension Manager